# making your app available to 3rd party applications

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

i want to integrate my application with 3rd party application, my understanding is that both application can agree of a action which can be used in intent filter for any activity to be exported which could be used when 3rd party app fires the intent with that particular action in it, any body has a better approach to this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom action string to identify your activity is a fine solution. Be sure to make it sufficiently unique (e.g., `com.commonsware.android.myapp.THIS_IS_MY_BOOMSTICK`) so you do not run into problems with other applications accidentally choosing the same action.